# How to trigger click event on amCharts?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have the below code, but the event is not triggering. Please help me with an answer of fiddle example.

Note: Only using `AmCharts.makeChart()` method.

```
function allGraph( toDate, fromDate ) {
  IndiviGraph( datasource, graphLines );
}

function IndiviGraph( datasource, graphLines ) {
  var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv1", {
    // category axis and stuff
  } );

  chart.addListener( "clickGraphItem", function( event ) {
    alert( "yello" );
  } );
}
```

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle

Comment: Please consider posting your whole chart config. The answer might largely depend on it. I don't want to speculate on it.

Comment: Are your sure your event is ClickGraphItem?..Let know if you are using a serial chart or pie-chart.